# JNI Error when Wrapping Jar with JOGL using Launch4j

Tags: opengl, java, jogl

I have been trying to wrap my fat JAR file into an EXE using Launch4j, but I have been running into problems when I try to execute the EXE. Here is the error log I get from Launch4j:

```
Executing: E:\Downloads\CasualCaving.exe
JNILibLoaderBase: Caught IllegalArgumentException: No Jar name in <jar:file:/E:/Downloads/CasualCaving.exe!/jogamp/common/Debug.class>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: E:\Downloads\natives\windows-amd64\\gluegen-rt.dll
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibraryInternal(JNILibLoaderBase.java:624)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.access$000(JNILibLoaderBase.java:63)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase$DefaultAction.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:106)
    at com.jogamp.common.jvm.JNILibLoaderBase.loadLibrary(JNILibLoaderBase.java:487)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle$GlueJNILibLoader.loadLibrary(DynamicLibraryBundle.java:421)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:317)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:287)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:147)
    at org.graphics.Render.<init>(Render.java:20)
    at org.engine.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

I am using JOGL 2.3.2 imported through Maven, with the assembly plugin to compile it to a fat JAR. Here is a picture of my library configuration:

[image: My project configuration screen]

I am not sure what is wrong, as the JAR file works fine.

Comment: Have you verified that this file exists in the folder it's being sought? `E:\Downloads\natives\windows-amd64\\gluegen-rt.dll` That double-backslash at the end looks suspicious, like it was expecting a path without a trailing backslash and added one, but the provided path already had one.

Comment: @DMGregory that fixed it! I just had to provide all of the JOGL natives for each platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you need to include all native DLLs need for each platform. Just go to the library location and extract the natives from the jar file for the desired platform.